# Fermat little theorem : show that if $p$ is prime, then $a^p \equiv a\pmod p$ holds, if $p$ divides $a$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Fermat little theorem : show that if $p$ is prime, then $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ holds,if $p$ divides $a$.

I know it doesn't hold but I'm having a hard time proving it..

I know that if $p$ divides $a$ then the $\gcd(a,p)$ is $p$

I also know that $a^p \equiv 0 \pmod p$  if $p$ divides $a$.

But I don't how to bring all that together into a proof. help please

Comment: "Either $1$ or $p$"? Why not just $p$?

Comment: Which of Fermat's theorems do you mean? [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)? If so, which version?

Comment: because if a prime number is divisible by 1 and it self

Answer (score 1):

One can generalize Fermat and [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\rm\color{blue}{(E)}$ to handle such. Below is one way.

**Theorem** $\ \ \, n^{\large k+\phi}\equiv n^{\large k}\pmod{p^i q^j}\ \ $ if $\,p\ne q\,$ are prime, $ \ \color{#0a0}{\phi(p^i),\phi(q^j)\mid \phi},\, $  $\, i,j \le k.\ \ \ $

${\bf Proof}\,\ \ p\nmid n\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm mod\ }p^i\!:\  n^{ \phi}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, n^{k + \phi}\equiv n^k,\ $ by $\,\  n^{\Large \color{#0a0}\phi} = (n^{\color{#0a0}{\Large \phi(p^{ i})}})^{\large \color{#0a0}\ell}\overset{\color{blue}{\rm (E)}}\equiv 1^{\large \ell}\equiv 1$

$\qquad\quad\ \ \color{#c00}{p\mid n}\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm mod\ }p^i\!:\  n^k\equiv 0\,\equiv\, n^{k + \phi}\ $ by $\ n^k = n^{k-i} \color{#c00}n^i = n^{k-i} (\color{#c00}{mp})^i$ and $\,k\ge i$

So $\ p^i\mid n^{k+\phi}\!-n^k.\,$ By symmetry $\,q^j$ divides it too, so their lcm $ = p^iq^j\,$ divides it too. $\ $ **QED**

**Remark** $\ $ The proof immediately extends to an arbitrary number of primes. See also [Carmichael's Lambda function,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) a generalization of [Euler's phi function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Answer (score 0):

If $p|a$ then $a\equiv 0\pmod p$. So $a^{p-1}\equiv 0\pmod p$.

Comment: thats what i have but i feel like i have to say more