# Proving $n^a-n^b$ is divisible by 10

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $n$ be positive integer. Prove that there exists positive integers $a$ and $b$, with $a \neq b$, such that $n^a-n^b$ is divisible by $10$.

I have tried using mathematical induction and logs but I am really stuck .

Comment: Hint: pigeonhole principle.

Comment: additional hint: reminders modulo 10

Comment: Just to clarify, It doesn't make sense to prove it by induction.

The question is not asking to prove it for all values of $n$ ,

You just need to prove it for one value.

Ironically, You just need the base case. Not the induction step

Comment: Hint: by the PigeonHole Principle, two of the $\color{#c00}{11}$ integers $\,n^0,n^1,n^2,\ldots,n^{10}$ must leave the same remainder when divided by $\color{#c00}{10},\,$ since there are only $\,\color{#c00}{10}\,$ possible remainders (pigeonholes) $\,0,1,2,\ldots,9.\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Have you ever noticed that $n$ and $n^5$ always end in the same digit? For example $2^5 = 32$, $3^5 = 243$, $4^5 = 1024$, ...

Comment: **Generally** $ \ n^{\large k+\phi}\equiv n^{\large k}\pmod{p^i q^j}\  $ if $\,p\ne q\,$ are prime, $ \ \color{}{\phi(p^i),\phi(q^j)\mid \phi},\, $  $\, i,j \le k.\  $ For a proof [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1175495/242) But a pigeonhole-based proof is simpler here in the OP.

Comment: +1. Very nice. OP can be solve induction with this observation Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Here is way of proving that $n^5-n$ works by induction, just so you know it can be done. It does rely on knowing the answer. The pigeonhole answer is the easiest elementary argument, but doesn't tell you which powers to use, and a more sophisticated approach tells you in general which powers will work for numbers other than $10$.

First note that $1^5-1=0$ is divisible by $10$.

Now for the induction step:

$$(n+1)^5-(n+1)=n^5+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n+1-n-1=(n^5-n)+10(n^3+n^2)+5n(n^3+1)$$

Now $n(n^3+1)=n(n+1)(n^2-n+1)$ is divisible by both $n$ and $n+1$, so is even (there are other ways of seeing this) so that $5n(n^3+1)$ is divisible by $10$.

Hence if $n^5-n$ is divisible by $10$ so is $(n+1)^5-(n+1)$, and the induction goes through.